# Combining Java 8 Optionals

Tags: java, option-type

I have two methods in my code:

```
Optional<CourseId> getCourseId(){
// returns just 1 course    
}

Optional<StudentId> getStudentId(CourseId courseId){
//returns an optional studentId
}
```

I am trying to combine these two methods to get something like this:

```
Optional<CourseId> crsid = getCourseId();
if ( crsid.isPresent() ){
    return getStudentId(crsid.get());
}
else{
    return Optional.empty()
}
```

How can I combine the above logic into an optional map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Optional::flatMap` method

```
return getCourseId().flatMap(id -> getStudentId(id));
```

Comment: crsId is an Optional type. getStudentId accepts a CourseId. Should it be: return getCourseId().flatMap(crsId -> getStudentId(Optional.of(crsId).get());

Comment: @DebsankarMukhopadhyay no, you got confused by name. I renamed it. In `flatMap` you have access to the value of optional

Comment: maybe `getCourseId().flatMap(this::gettudentId)` (assuming `this` is the correct instance, not static)